# If statement not capturing the conditional I'm seeking

Tags: dictionaries, python

I'm working on a hw assignment, and my if statement isn't working the way it's intended.

This is an ATM machine project. I've already gotten the program to read the csv file and stored it into a dictionary with the pin number as the key.

What I can't get it to do is find the pin number in my getUser() function. Below is the code and under that is the IDLE result. Please help!

```
d = {}
def startUp(fname):
    try:
        acct_file = open(fname,'r')
        for line in acct_file:
            (key,first,last,balance) = line.split(',')
            d[int(key)] = [last,first,float(balance)]
        print(d)
        getUser()
    except:
        print('Cannot get to the file')


def getUser():
    user_pin = int(input('What is your pin number? '))
    if user_pin in d.keys():
        return (user_pin,first,True)
    else:
        print('Incorrect Pin')
        return (None,None,False)
```

IDLE result:
What is your pin number? 9967
*this returns nothing*

Comment: It returns nothing, but that pin number is in the file.

Comment: Hi Dennis! Unfortunately, this site is mostly for theoretical computer science; practical programming issues, like this one, will get better answers on StackOverflow.